# Origin of barber/surgeons: did it have to do with tools?

Tags: technology, medicine

Although today it sounds absurd that someone who shaved men and I guess also cut hair would be entrusted to performing medical procedures, is it possible that few people had the tools or the ability to make and maintain tools which had sharp edges and from this the combined profession arose?

That is to say, perhaps having the metallurgical skills to make and maintain a razor was rare enough that few people could become barbers and so that the ability to shave someone was in turn quite rare and being a barber was considered a much more skilled profession than it is today?

I think of the Bertrand Russel math paradox about shaving all men who do not shave themselves -- could the 19th century be the first century in which high quality razors became available to the public and prior to that most men either wore beards or those who could afford it were shaved by professionals?

What I find difficult to believe is that being a surgeon was ever considered an unskilled profession considering what the stakes were -- from this I conclude that both barber and surgeon were both considered to be highly skilled professions.

Note that the wikipedia entry for Barber Surgeon says that barbers were sought to perform surgery because they had razors and maybe that implies that indeed the implements were hard to come by.

**I am looking for metallurgy as being part of the explanation. Whereas any town might have a blacksmith who could would with large items, making a small item like a razor would seem to be a very different skill. I do not know what the profession who made razors was called -- I doubt if blacksmiths did this and perhaps barber surgeons tended to make their own tools.**

Comment: OK, so the first question is: Where have you already looked?

Comment: I have read many articles, including of course the wikipedia entry for barber surgeon, but I can't find anything that connects the tools themselves and the difficulty in making/maintaining them to this combination of professions -- I hope it is clear that this is the question. It is mentioned that barbers had razors in the wiki article so perhaps this implies that such implements were hard to come by.

Comment: You should work that into your post.

Comment: Barbers got into dentistry first: [History of Dentistry: From Barber-Surgeons to Dentists | History Daily](https://historydaily.org/history-dentistry-barber-surgeons-dentists).
As for surgery, until recent times, physicians cured all problems with medicine and didn't perform surgery, though they often had a non-respected assistant surgeon to do amputations etc.
In some countries (e.g. Britain), surgeons are still called "Mr.", not "Dr.".
If you had a problem that might be corrected by surgery and you didn't want it to be treated with medicine alone, the barber was the obvious person to ask.

Comment: You missed an important detail - in the same sentence of the Wikipedia article you glossed over for barbers' possession of tools, you missed the part about "coordination indispensable to their trade" -- their profession involved being _very careful_ with sharp things around other people.

Comment: @Spencer yes which further implies that razors were rare.

Comment: @releseabe I don't think so. It's more about not letting someone near you with a knife who would more likely than not cut off their own finger or accidentally nick your carotid.

Comment: In a largely agrarian society, cutting tools - saws, axes etc - must have been commonplace. As @Spencer says, it was the ability to use them with precision that barbers possessed. Also, in surgery with no anaesthetic, primitive antiseptics (alcohol) etc, **speed** was crucial - the faster a tooth was pulled, or a limb, amputated, the the less shock, hence a better the prognosis.

Comment: Barbers were not blacksmith, so had no advantage in creating those tools or anything like that. I think you are missing a point: do bookshops has any unique advantage in creating or sourcing books? No, they just happen to be the ones who operate a shop. In a village or in war the barbers were the ones who were around, had sharp tools and good hands, and no one could afford to have a specialist, so they have done the job.

Answer (score 2):

> In [the Middle Ages], surgery was seldom conducted by physicians, but instead by barbers, who, possessing razors **and coordination** indispensable to their trade, were called upon for numerous tasks ranging from cutting hair to amputating limbs.

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_surgeon),  "barber-surgeon"

I doubt it has anything to do with any scarcity of tools.  If tools are rare, people with the skill to use them well are rarer still.

You get a barber to shave you or cut your hair because they can do it properly, without harming you.  You don't want to let someone near you with a knife who would more likely than not cut off their own finger or accidentally nick your carotid.

Such people would have been useful for battlefield surgery as well.

Medieval barbers were trained through a system of apprenticeship, so during that time, they would have had their masters' tools to work with, and gotten their own when they "graduated" (or whatever term was used back then).